# 1 second white screen while a winForm is loading with a picture in PictureBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

There is a form. On the form there is a pictureBox docked on all form's surface.
When app starts, for a second a form with white surface is displayed, then
the picture is shown.

how can i get rid of that 1s white form?

Comment: Please rephrase your question to be more clear.

Comment: We'll need some code to further help you.

Comment: I have assigned the image to PictureBox's Image property at design time. When I run the application and the form is being loaded, the form is first displayed with white screen (for a 1 second) then the image appear.

Comment: Are you running it in Debug mode?

Comment: Sounds like you are doing something time consuming in form_Shown event. Call Form's Refresh() methdod as the first thing in form shown -event and it will first draw the form, then do the time consuming things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are doing something time consuming in form_Shown event. Call Form's Refresh() method as the first thing in form shown -event and it will first draw the form, then do the time consuming things

Answer (score 1):

You have not stated when you are loading the picturebox with your image. But I would try making your picturebox visible at the end of your Form_Load event or in your Form_Shown event.

Comment: Picture is assigned in the Image property of the PictureBox component at design time.

Comment: Set your picturebox visibility to false in the designer and try what I suggested

Comment: Sorry, but it behaves the same way.

Comment: 400 X 200 px. To be precise, when I run the app, I see the form's border, which loads first, then rest things appear.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds more like a threading problem to me. I guess that your UI thread **is doing too much work** and cannot update the UI often enough.

Do all of the following:

- Make sure loading and processing any data (including the images) is NOT located in the constructors.
- Move that code into the appropriate FormLoad() event handler methods.
- Implement loading of the images so that it runs a separate thread.

You can find some advice in this MSDN article: [Give Your .NET-based Application a Fast and Responsive UI with Multiple Threads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300429.aspx)

If you are working in a .NET 4.x version, you can also use the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) to make working with multiple threads easier.

The upcoming .NET 4.5 also offers the even more comfortable await and asyc keywords: [Asynchronous Programming with Async and Await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).